# über anstatt seit über

Tags: grammaticality, adverb

Ich schaue gerade eine TV Serie ( The West Wing Staffel 1
Folge 1 ) und der folgende Satz von der Serie ließ mich zweifeln, ob man *seit über* auf (einfach) *über* verkürzen darf.

Ich kenne ihn (seit) über 40 Jahren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit *kennen* lassen sich verschiedene Zeitangaben verbinden:

> Ich kenne ihn jetzt *seit ein**em** Wochenende*.
>
> Ich kenne ihn jetzt *ein**e** Woche*.

Hier gibt *seit* plus **Dativ** den Beginn an, während der temporale **Akkusativ** im zweiten Beispiel die Dauer angibt. Parallel dazu, ohne Bedeutungsunterschied:

> A) Ich kenne ihn *seit 40 Jahre**n***.
>
> B) Ich kenne ihn *40 Jahr**e***.

*Über* ist mehrdeutig. Es kann eine temporale Präposition mit Akkusativ sein:

> Wir sind *über**s** Wochenende* weggefahren.

Es kann aber auch als Adverb das Überschreiten einer Grenze ausdrücken:

> Ich kenne ihn *über 40 Jahre*.
> = Ich kenne ihn länger als 40 Jahre.

Als Adverb hat *über* keinen Einfluss auf den Kasus der Gruppe, auf die es sich bezieht. In den Beispielsätzen A und B lässt sich das Adverb einsetzen:

> A') Ich kenne ihn *seit über 40 Jahre**n***.
>
> B') Ich kenne ihn *über 40 Jahr**e***.

Eine mit *über* vergleichbare Mehrdeutigkeit zwischen Präposition und Adverb hat *bis (zu)*.

> *Bis nächst**e** Woche*, *bis zu**m** Abgabetermin* muss das erledigt sein. (Präposition)
>
> Das kann *(bis zu) ein**en** Monat* dauern. (Adverb)

Comment: Danke! Ich glaube, ich habe es jetzt kapiert!

Answer (score 1):

Nein aber ja. (oder: ja, aber nein).

"Seit" erfordert den Dativ. Ohne "seit" folgt eine Zeitspanne im Akkusativ (Oder ist es Nominativ?):

> Ich kenne ihn seit über 30 Jahren.

> Ich kenne ihn über 30 Jahre.

Das "über" hat keinen Einfluss auf die Deklination und kann ohne Änderung der Grammatik weggelassen werden.